# Combining multiple .tiff files obtained after download from Google Earth Engine?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, merge, google-earth-engine

I downloaded some of my classified images from GEE using the following script-

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: input.clip(district),
  description: 'Test',
  maxPixels: 499295920080,
  scale: 30
});
```

But since my image was large, it was broken down into 16 .tiff files during download. Now I am required to do some post processing on my complete classified image as a whole, but I can't figure out how to combine these images back into a single jpeg/.tiff image.

Can someone guide me towards a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Virtual Raster mosaic from them with GDAL, that most GDAL based/agnostic GIS tools (Qgis, ArcMap,...) will be able to handle.

`gdalbuildvrt Test-mosaic.vrt Test*.tif`

This will work on a linux/unix system. On Windows you might be better off using the `-input_file_list` parameter of [gdalbuildvrt](https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html).

If you want to create a GeoTiff from the VRT you can use:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff Test-mosaic.vrt Test-mosaic.tif`

Comment: Using this command I got a Test-mosaic.vrt file, but is there a way to convert this to .tif or to read it directly pixel-wise?

Comment: You can convert the VRT to a GeoTiff with `gdal_translate` (included in my edit). However - for any software that can read VRTs this is not necessary, as it will be handled internally.